# CSS not working on my HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add some css to my button and for some reason this is not working.

Index page

```
<input style="margin-top:10px;" type="submit" class="loginButton" title="Subscribe" value="Subscribe" />
```

CSS

```
.loginButton {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #9e0000), color-stop(1, #ff0000));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #9e0000 5%, #ff0000 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #9e0000 5%, #ff0000 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #9e0000 5%, #ff0000 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #9e0000 5%, #ff0000 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9e0000 5%, #ff0000 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9e0000', endColorstr='#ff0000',GradientType=0);
    background-color: #9e0000;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #1c0101;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 18px 44px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000000;
}
```

What could this be? as I used this style before.

Comment: what exactly is not working ? all of it ?

Comment: I don't understand. It works perfectly for me. Is this your desired result: https://jsfiddle.net/NikolaosG/6crb2nof/ ?

Comment: Is your CSS being included properly? The class matches that of the class on the button in the HTML so it should work without issues.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in console?

Comment: not an error, its just not working :S

Comment: Are you using internal or external CSS? If you are using the latter then make sure you point to the right path.

Answer (score 0):

It works pretty well for me

[image]

Double check your CSS paths and class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

It's working. Make sure to include the correct path for external CSS or if you are using inside the html file, make sure to mention the css script inside 
 `<style type="text/css"></style>`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkrJ8.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is working fine and please double check you code, if not just add the `css` class as shown below (add the class with `input`)

```
input.loginButton{ /*HERE YOU CAN ADD YOUR CSS CODE*/}
```